# preg_replace trouble

Tags: php

am trying to leave only a-zA-Z0-9._ in a text using :

```
$new_pgname=preg_replace('|(^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.])|s','',$new_pgname);
```

but guess what ... right , it's not working ! any help plz ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$new_pgname=preg_replace('%[^a-z0-9._]%i', '', $new_pgname);
```

This will maintain upper and lowercase characters

Answer (score 3):

What you should do - replace one or many characters that are NOT `a-z A-Z 0-9 _ or .`. So you need to use the following expression: `[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+`

What this means:

`[]` - define a character class

`^` - NOT these characters

`+` - one or more

Code:

```
$new_pgname = "(*_&HF&)*FH)FE*H)_#(*#F(*&HEF&HF*&By7bv07f87asFB087aFgbh08aj9smf,f.,efw3.g3454-w54w.34.tw\43t4/.g34/g34g/3g434h8j)*7bh*&)Fg803723r6y";
echo $new_pgname . '<br />';
$new_pgname = preg_replace ('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+/', '', $new_pgname);
echo $new_pgname . '<br />';
```

OUTPUT:

```
(*_&HF&)*FH)FE*H)_#(*#F(*&HEF&HF*&By7bv07f87asFB087aFgbh08aj9smf,f.,efw3.g3454-w54w.34.tw#t4/.g34/g34g/3g434h8j)*7bh*&)Fg803723r6y<br />
_HFFHFEH_FHEFHFBy7bv07f87asFB087aFgbh08aj9smff.efw3.g3454w54w.34.twt4.g34g34g3g434h8j7bhFg803723r6y<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to escape the dot (.) inside an alternation

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the carat /in/side the bracket

Answer (score 0):

What you have will only attempt to match characters at the beginning of the string...the caret (`^`) goes inside the character group to negate it.

```
$new_pgname=preg_replace('|([^a-zA-Z0-9_\.])|s','',$new_pgname);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use a negated character range. In order to do that, you need to put the caret (^) inside the square braces, as the first character of the set, i.e.:

[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]